# Initialize an instance of a class that has only Property type variables. JavaFX

Tags: javafx-2

I have a class that has some variables of SimpleStringProperty type. When this class is initialized by using a no argument constructor like this: `Foo f = new Foo();`, then the SimpleStringProperty variables are not initialized. Therefore I have to initialize that instance like this: `Foo f = new Foo(null, null);`

But, is there any other simple/clean way to initilize instance of such classes? I have also tried to extend the class like this:

`public class Foo extends StringPropertyBase{//...}`,

but still no argument constructor doesn't initialize the variables.

Foo.java

```
public class Foo{
    private SimpleStringProperty x;
    private SimpleStringProperty y;

    public Foo(String a, String b){
        this.x = new SimpleStringProperty(a);
        this.x = new SimpleStringProperty(b);
    }

    public StringProperty xProperty(){return x;}
    public StringProperty yProperty(){return y;}
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just do something like this which initialises them to the empty string `""`?

```
public Foo() {
    this.x = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    this.y = new SimpleStringProperty("");
}
```

Obviously this can be changed to provide any sane defaults you wish.

The properties can then be changed at another time by anything that is bound to it or by providing setters that allow the property to be updated, something like this:

```
public void setX(String value) {
    this.xProperty().set(value);
}
```